# Share data in angular using flux architecture

Tags: angularjs, flux

We are using angular with flux architecture. How do we share data (input data), between two separate modules?

Comment: You can create a store and watch like `$scope.$watch(MyStore.getItems())` for any changes dispatched by `MyStore`. [Reference](https://github.com/christianalfoni/flux-angular#testing-stores)

Comment: @tsuz If Store1 has to update input values based on Store2 selected options, how do we go about it?

Comment: When an option is chosen, you dispatch an action in Store2. Simultaneously, you can also dispatch an action in Store1 and that change in value can be watched by whoever.